# Tableau Rest API signin keeps on giving 401001 Signin error

Tags: tableau-api

I have read numerous posts on this and other Tableau forum, I have read through the documentation several times, but still while trying to login to the Tableau using the REST API, I keep on getting errors.

I have double checked the contentUrl (tried with both empty string and actual side ID obtained from the site settings). For the username, I have tried the useremail@domain.com, username as shown in the account settings, and even added the local\username as shown in the account settings. But nothing still, I keep on getting the 401001 error.

Its a bit frustrating that the API is not designed properly as the return value can give two possible errors - either username/password incorrect or contentUrl is wrong. A right API should have given 401001 for username/password failure and something else, like 401002 for content Url failure.

Am using the below in Postman (I've tried the XML version also, but keep getting the same error):

```
https://my--tab--server.---ondemand.com/api/2.8/auth/signin

{
  "credentials": {
    "name": "my----username---",
    "password": "my-----password",
    "site": {
      "contentUrl": "HR"
    }
  }
}
```

Response is:

```
<error code="401001">
    <summary>Signin Error</summary>
    <detail>Error signing in to Tableau Server</detail>
</error>
```

Am able to successfully logon to the web portal using the same user credentials.

So, what can I be doing wrong here? Any inputs would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have finally found the reasons! The Tableau server is configured to use SAML for SSO signin, and Tableau REST APIs specifically don't work with SAML!

> Note: The REST API does not use SAML single-sign (SSO) authentication.
>   To sign in, you must specify the name and password of a user who has
>   been created on the server. The user could have a local or Active
>   Directory account, depending on how you have configured Tableau
>   Server. For Tableau Online, you can specify the TableauID credentials
>   of the user. You will have the permissions of the user that you're
>   signed in as. You cannot use a SAML account for sign in when you use
>   the REST API. For information about the requirements for using SAML,
>   see SAML Requirements.

So, I'll now need to create a native Tableau user and try that with the REST API. Hope that works.